# Recuperar dados redirectaction mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho uma consulta de estudantes,

```
// POST: /Admin/Anuncio
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Estudante estudante)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            List<EstudantesEncontrados> list = GetEstudante(GetEstudanteProximo(estudante));

            if (list != null)
            {
                TempData["ListaEstudantesEncontrados"] = list;
                return RedirectToAction("Lista", "Busca");

            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Erro Ao pesquisar");
            }

        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View();

    }
```

caso encontre os estudantes redireciona para a listagem dos estudantes encontrados, quando eu atualizo a página na listagem dos estudantes ele dá um erro na view pois a TempData["ListaEstudantesEncontrados"] que manda a MODEL está vindo null da action acima, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma quando for atualizado o navegador ele pegue os dados que foram enviados no form anteriormente.

```
public ActionResult Lista()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "";

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (TempData["ListaEstudantesEncontrados"] != null)
            {
                var model = TempData["ListaEstudantesEncontrados"] as List<EstudantesEncontrados>;
                return View(model); ;
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Erro ao consultar");
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"});
            }
        }else{
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }           

    }
```

Comment: Lisbão, eu to acreditando que o erro ta na view, por favor poste a sua view?

Answer (score 2):

Este código está bem errado. `TempData` não deve ser usado para enviar informações de uma pesquisa para a `View`.

Crie um `ViewModel` para o Estudante:

### ViewModels\EstudanteViewModel

```
public class EstudanteViewModel {
    /* Coloque aqui properties que vão corresponder aos parâmetros em tela */

    public virtual IList<Estudante> EstudantesEncontrados {get;set;}
}
```

No Controller, modifique o seguinte:

```
// POST: /Anuncios/Index
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post | HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult Index(EstudanteViewModel viewModel = null)
{
    if (viewModel != null && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var list = GetEstudante(GetEstudanteProximo(estudante));

        if (list != null)
        {
            viewModel.EstudantesEncontrados = list;
            return View(viewModel);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Erro Ao pesquisar");
        }

    }

    return View(new EstudantesViewModel());
}
```

Assim você manda um objeto `EstudanteViewModel` preenchido para o `Controller` e pode pesquisar por ele. Caso este objeto não esteja devidamente preenchido, exibe uma `View` vazia.

Sendo assim, a Action `Lista` não é mais necessária, visto que você pode usar a lista do `ViewModel` para exibir seus resultados em tela.

Answer (score 2):

O Cigano alertou muito bem, realmente enviar sua coleção para a View usando **TempData** não é a forma mais correta.

Da forma que ele sugeriu, fica interessante, mas uma observação importante: "sua View precisa ser tipada, ou seja, do tipo **EstudanteViewModel**".

**TempData** é bastante útil para exibir mensagem temporárias, tais como mensagens de sucesso após um cadastro, por exemplo:

**Controler:**

```
public class EstudanteController : Controller
{ 
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Salvar()
    {
         //Código para salvar um Estudante.
         TempData["mensagem"] = "Mensagem de sucesso";
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

**View:** (Index)

```
@model EstudanteViewModel   

<div>
    @TempData["mensagem"]
</div>

//Código restante...
```

Após ser redirecionado para a view Index, a mensagem em TempData é exibida.